# How can I find unused classes/files in git/WebStorm?

Tags: git, webstorm

I am trying to clean up my angularjs project. We are using github as a repository.

How can I select all not used classes/services etc using a git command? I am also using WebStorm how can I select these with that?

Comment: I tried the inspect code feature but it did not return an error for unused controllers I have defined in my coffeescript?

Answer (score 3):

Git itself manages data without any knowledge of their actual meaning: it doesn't analyze the sources.

For webstorm, you would need a tool capable of doing such an analysis and find unused classes.
For example, [JetBrain webstorm features](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/) include a Validation and Quick-Fixes section with unused CSS classes detection. Or use [other analysis tools like Appcode](http://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/2014/01/appcode-inspections-for-your-code-perfection/).

But Git itself wouldn't be able to help in that matter.